# Find the relationship between $S_0(\phi x)$ with $S_1(x)$

Tags: probability, statistics, self-learning

> Let $T$ the survival time of patients with $F(.)$ and $S_T(x)=P(T>x)$
>   the cumulative distribution function and the survival function. Take a
>   covariate $Z$ such that $$Z=\begin{cases}0 \qquad group 0\\1 \qquad
>  group1 \end{cases}$$ Then
>
> $S_0(x)=P(T>x;Z=0)$
>
> $S_1(x)=P(T>x;Z=1)$
>
> Taking $S_0(\phi x)=S_1(x)$ for $\phi\in \mathbb{R}$, find the relationship between the
>   probability density functions and the risk functions.

I don't know what I need to do in this question. Let
$$S_1(x)=P(T>x)=1-P(T\leq x)$$
then
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}S_1(x)=-f_T(x)$$
So if $S_0(\phi x)=S_1(x)$

$$S_1(x)=S_0(\phi x)\Rightarrow P(T>\phi x)=P(T>x)$$

but it's true just if $\phi=1$. Anyone have any idea what I need to do? It can be a typo in $T$ where it should be $T_1$ and $T_2$?

Comment: As you wrote yourself, $S_i(x) \neq P(T > x)$, $i=1,2$.

Comment: As far as I can tell, $S_0$ has to satisfy the differential equation

$S_0'(x) + \phi S_0'(\phi x) = -f_T(x)$,

with - I think - boundary condition $S_0(0)=0$.

I derived this by using $P(T > x) = S_0(x) + S_1(x)$.